# Variables not in global scope file include

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I am trying to assign variables out of global scope and allow a included file with access to these vars. This is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        var cm_url = "http://test.com/mikelbring/1313-myproducthere";
        var cm_text = "Buy";
        var z = document.createElement("script");
        z.src = "button.js";
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(z, s);
    })();
</script>
```

The script doesn't have access to the vars. What can I do to give it access to the vars but keep them out of the global scope? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're using a self-executing function to limit the scope of those variables. At some point, you've got to expose *something* in the global scope so that the other scripts can access them.

Might I suggest a simple [namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration) or [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript):

```
var MIKEL = {
    cm_url: "http://test.com/mikelbring/1313-myproducthere",
    cm_text: "Buy",
    // etc...
};
```

...or even something more standard/library-ish, like [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) or [CommonJS](http://www.commonjs.org/specs/modules/1.0/).